# Why does this method to solve a quadratic equation for $x$ omit $x=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Here is a simple quadratic equation:

$$9x^2 - 36x = 0$$

We proceed as following:
\begin{align*}
9x^2 & = 36x\\
9x & = 36\\
x & = 4
\end{align*}

So, *we get* $x=4$.

But, here's another way:
\begin{align*}
9x^2 - 36x & = 0\\
x(9x-36) & = 0\\
\end{align*}

Therefore, $\boldsymbol{x=0}$ *or* $x=4$.

What's the problem in the first method that doesn't allow $x$ to be $0$?

Comment: When you divide each side by $x$, you assume that $x\neq 0$. But, if this is not the case, then ...

Comment: The problem is that you can't divide by $x$ if $x=0$.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: In the first way it is asumed $x\ne 0$ which is obvious

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the step going from $9x^2=36x$ to $9x=36$, you divided by $x$.
As you cannot divide by 0, this step is only valid for $x \ne 0$. So you lost the solution $x=0$ with this transformation.

Answer (score 5):

To solve an equation, you have to establish a sequence of logical **equivalences**.

In your first method, you only established a sequence of logical **implications**. This is the reason why you lost the solution $x=0$.

*Remark:* In order to solve an equation, an sequence of **implications** can fails for two reasons:

1. You lost one (o more than one) "right solution".
2. You find one (or more then one) "wrong solution".

   - Example 1 (provided by you):
     $$\begin{align}
     &9x^2-36x=0\\
     \Rightarrow\quad&9x^2=36x\\
     \Rightarrow\quad&9x=36\qquad \text{if } x\neq 0\\
     \Rightarrow\quad&x=4\qquad \text{if } x\neq 0\\
     \end{align}$$
     Here, we lost the right solution $x=0$.
   - Example 2:
     $$\begin{align}
     &x^2+1=0\\
     \Rightarrow\quad&(x^2+1)(x^2-1)=0(x^2-1)\\
     \Rightarrow\quad&x^4-1=0\\
     \Rightarrow\quad&x^4=1\\
     \Rightarrow\quad&x=1\\
     \end{align}$$
     Here, we find the wrong solution $x=1$.
   - Example 3 (provided by you too):
     $$\begin{align}
     &9x^2-36x=0\\
     \Leftrightarrow\quad&x(9x-36)=0\\
     \Leftrightarrow\quad&x=0\text{ or }9x-36=0\\
     \Leftrightarrow\quad&x=0\text{ or }x=4\\\end{align}$$
     Here, we lost nothing right and find nothing wrong.
   - Example 4:
     $$\begin{align}
     &9x^2-36x=0\\
     \Leftrightarrow\quad&9x^2=36x\\
     \Leftrightarrow\quad&9x=36 \text{ if } x\neq 0\qquad \text { or } \qquad x=0\\
     \Leftrightarrow\quad&x=4\text { or }x=0\\
     \end{align}$$
     Here, we solved the equation because we established a sequence of equivalences.

Comment: Which is the wrong step in the 2nd example?

Comment: And does the symbol '⇔' signify something special in 3rd example?

Comment: @Perceptioner There is nothing wrong. Each implication is valid. However, *implications* are not *equivalences*. So, the values which satisfy the last line are not the same values which satisfy the first line; in other words, we didn't solve the equation because we didn't establish a sequence of equivalences. So, the question is: what step is not an equivalence? Which respect to the second comment, yes, $\Rightarrow$ means "implies" and $\Leftrightarrow$ means "is equivalent to". [See this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49589/implication-and-equivalence-arrows-when-to-use-them).

Comment: @Perceptioner The algebra of your first method is not useless. Instead, it can be used to solve the equation. But you have to be careful. See my Example 4.

Comment: +1 Always happy for the answers that go that one (or more) step to provide as much explanation (including counter/examples) as possible. Thanks, keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

You divided by $x$. Note that since you cannot divide by $0$, dividing by $x$ is similar to as asserting that $x$ is not $0$.

Of course, this argument is not rigourous, consider $x^3-x^2=0$. Even when we divide by $x$, we have $x(x-1)=0$, so $0$ and $1$ are solutions to the equation after dividing by $x$.

In summary, the best way is to check if whatever you are dividing by is $0$, if it is, you should try factoring the expression instead.