# Why is squaring both sides not producing extraneous roots here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

**Process $1$:**

$$2x-1=0$$

$$2x=1$$

$$x=\frac{1}{2}$$

**Process $2$:**

$$2x-1=0$$

$$(2x-1)^2=0$$

$$(2x-1)(2x-1)=0$$

$$2x-1=0$$

$$2x=1$$

$$x=\frac{1}{2}$$

Why aren't we getting extraneous roots in process $2$?

Comment: You *are* getting an extra root: $x=1/2$ is a *double* root of the quadratic.

Comment: @NickD, an extraneous root is not the same as an extra root.  An extraneous root is one that does not solve the original equation.

Comment: The original equation has one root. If you square it, you have two roots: one of them is extraneous by my definition, but YMMV.

Comment: If x= 1 then x^2= 1 which has two roots, 1 and -1.  But if x=0 then x^2= which has only x=1 as root.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't get extraneous roots because you're squaring zero.  There is only one value that, when squared, gives zero.  If you did it with a non-zero value, you would add extraneous roots, because there would be a second number that has the same square.

Comment: @lonestudent what does that counterexample have to do with what I said?

Comment: I have no idea what you’re saying.  The problem isn’t that you get the same value when squaring; it’s that there is no other value has a square equal to zero, in contrast to 1, which has 2 values with it has the square.

Comment: @lonestudent $0^2 = 0$, but $(-1)^2 = 1$ as well as $(+1)^2=1$
That is the argument. There are 2 numbers that when squared give rise to 1

Comment: @aaa Yes, now it is clear to me the meaning of this sentence: "If you did it with a non-zero value, you would add extraneous roots, because there would be a second number that has the same square"  very nice.

Answer (score 4):

Because extraneous roots aren't necessarily produced by squaring both sides. They are produced by setting a sequence of logical implications instead of a sequence of logical equivalences. See examples in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1588695/70305) .

In your case, it turns out that

$$\begin{aligned} &2x-1=0\\
\Leftrightarrow \quad&2x=1\\
\Leftrightarrow \quad &x=\tfrac{1}{2}\end{aligned}$$

as well as

$$\begin{aligned}&2x-1=0\\
\overset{*}\Leftrightarrow \quad&(2x-1)^2=0\\
\Leftrightarrow \quad&(2x-1)(2x-1)=0\\
\overset{**}\Leftrightarrow \quad&2x-1=0\\
\Leftrightarrow \quad&2x=1\\
\Leftrightarrow \quad&x=\tfrac{1}{2}\end{aligned}$$

In $*$ we can use "$\Leftrightarrow$" instead of "$\Rightarrow$" because $0$ has only one square root.

In $**$ we can use "$\Leftrightarrow$" without the restriction $x\neq\frac{1}{2}$ because $ab=0$ iff $a=0$ or $b=0$ (that is, we are not dividing by zero).

The other equivalences are straightforward.

Comment: It's the squaring of both sides that produces a logical implication instead of equivalence.  $x=y \rightarrow x^2 = y^2$ isn't reversible.  So your first sentence is incorrect.

Comment: @Paul Squaring produces a logical implication only if $y\neq 0$. Thus, in general, squaring does not produce extraneous roots.

Comment: @Paul I corrected the first sentence. I think it is clearer now.

Answer (score 3):

By [zero-product property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-product_property) we have that

$$A\cdot B=0 \iff A=0 \quad \lor \quad B=0$$

therefore

$$(2x-1)(2x-1)=0 \iff 2x-1=0 \quad \lor \quad 2x-1=0 \iff 2x-1=0 $$

Comment: Short and nice explanation!

Comment: @Pedro I've discussed why in this case we don't produce extraneous roots by squaring, which adresses the question posed. I haven't discuss how extraneous roots can be produced i general.

Comment: @lonestudent, user Oh, sorry. It makes sense now. I misunderstood it. I will delete my previous comment.