# Find the number of distinct equivalence classes $[f]$ of $R$.

Tags: functions, equivalence-relations

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of the set $\Bbb Z$ for all integers, and let $\mathscr F$ denote the set of all functions $f:A\rightarrow B.$

> Define a relation $R$ on $\mathscr F$ by : for any $f,g \in \mathscr F$,  $\;fRg\;$ if and only if $f - g$ is a constant function (i.e. there is a constant $c$ so that $f(x) - g(x) =c$ for all $x\in A$).

(a) Suppose that $A = B =\Bbb Z $. Let $I_Z$ be the identity function on $\Bbb Z$.  Find a function $f\neq I_Z$ which belongs to the equivalence class $[I_Z].$

Assume $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{1,2,...,n\}$ where $n\ge 2$ is a fixed integer.

(b) Find the number of functions $f \in \mathscr F$ so that $[f]= ${$f$ }

(c) Find the number of distinct equivalence classes $[f]$ of $R$.

Comment: (a) What about $f(x)=x+17$?

Comment: Nitpicking: when one defines something in mathematics (unlike in logic or in philosophy), one should use "if", and not "if and only if". See the paragraph on definitions [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if#Advanced_considerations).

Comment: @julien: I completely disagree here. When defining a piece of *terminology*, "if" is standard (although I still wouldn't call "if and only if" wrong). But here we are defining a specific set (namely the relation $R$); so we should specify exactly when something is in the set, not just a necessary condition.

Comment: @GregMartin When one defines something in mathematics, and here it is explicit that what is after $fRg$ is a definition, the use of "if" means an equivalence between the word, the symbol, the set, whatever is being defined, and the subsequent assertion. Not a sufficient (where you said necessary) condition. It goes like that in a majority of written mathematical works. And so you completely disagree with these. Not with me. But you can use "if and only if" in your definitions, I will still understand.

Comment: @GregMartin See [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169158/can-mathematical-definitions-of-the-form-p-if-q-be-interpreted-as-p-if-and-on). Or [that thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39022/alternative-ways-to-say-if-and-only-if). You'll be happy to see that Arturo Magidin uses "if and only if" in his definitions.

Comment: It seems you've completely missed the distinction I was drawing between defining terminology and defining a mathematical object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(b)$ **Hint** $g \in [f]$ if and only if $g=f+c$.

The only way in which $[f]=\{ f \}$ is if no other $f+c$ works. $f+c$ is a function on $A$, but might not have the range $\{ 1,2,3,..,n \}$

This tells you that $[f]=\{ f \}$ if and only if for all real numbers $c \neq 0$ the image of $f+c$ is not inside $\{ 1,2,3,..,n \}$. This tells you something about $f$ [ think which are the smallest and largest values $f$ can take].

(c) If $f$ is any function, then you can prove that there exists an unique function $f \in [f]$ so that $1 \in Im(g)$. That should help you find the answer....

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

(a) You've defined $R$ by saying two functions are related when they differ by a constant.  So try adding a constant to $I_{\mathbb Z}$.

(b) If $[f] = \{f\}$ then it must be that you can't shift $f$ up or down, so it must take the values $1$ and $n$ somewhere...

(c) You can always shift down so that $1$ is in the image of $f$.  This gives you a unique representative for the equivalence class of $f$.  So you need to count the number of functions $A \to B$ with $1$ in the image.