# Why is the definition of the monotonicity of a function an "if" statement and not an "iff" statement?

Tags: calculus, functions, logic, definition, monotone-functions

For the sake of simplicity, I will only consider the definition of a *strictly increasing* function:

"The function $f(x)$ is *strictly increasing* on an interval $K$ **if** $$\forall x_1, x_2 \in K, x_1 < x_2 \implies f(x_1)<f(x_2)." (1)$$

But then I came across this statement in my textbook:

"The function $f(x)$ is *strictly increasing* on an interval $K$ **if and only if** $$\forall x_1, x_2 \in K, x_1 \neq x_2 \implies \frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}>0." (2)$$
I've tried to prove $(2)$ using definition $(1)$ but I could only prove the "if". I think we need more than just definition $(1)$ to prove the "only if", which is weird. Right?

And based on that statement in my textbook, I can prove that:

"The function $f(x)$ is *strictly increasing* on an interval $K$ **if and only if** $$\forall x_1, x_2 \in K, x_1 < x_2 \iff f(x_1)<f(x_2)." (3)$$
Statement $(3)$ is obviously more detailed than $(1)$.

So to sum up, I have two questions: Do I really need more than definition $(1)$ to prove $(2)$? And why don't we make definition $(1)$ more detailed, like statement $(3)$?

Sorry it's kinda chaotic in here but I can't find a better way to organize my ideas.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Some authors don't state definitions as "if and only if"s, some authors do. This is only a question of convention. Generally, definitions should be understood to be if and only if statements.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin So (2) is more detailed than (1) since based on (2) it is implied that  $f(x_1)<f(x_2) \implies x_1<x_2$. Am I correct?

Comment: I misread (2) as a definition, sorry.

Comment: You can prove the converse in the first definition so we don't make it explicit.

Comment: OK since "if" in (1) can be interpreted as "if and only if", I can prove (2) using (1), which means "$x_1<x_2 \implies f(x_1)<f(x_2)$" itself implies $"f(x_1)<f(x_2) \implies x_1<x_2"$?

Comment: OK I think I got it. Thank you guys!

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/566565/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/169166/42969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitions are always understood to mean *if and only if* but often written as *if*.