# Definition of limit of functions

Tags: real-analysis

I know the definition of the limit of functions

> Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and let $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We say
> $$\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x) = \mathscr l$$
> if
> $(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall x \in A), 0 < |x-a| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - \mathscr l| < \epsilon$.

My question is can we say :

> Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and let $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. If
> $$\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x) = \mathscr l$$
> then
> $(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall x \in A), 0 < |x-a| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - \mathscr l| < \epsilon$.

**Note:** The question I was working on has a well-defined limit.

Many thanks

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/39022/1508) is relevant.

Comment: @TonyK Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although usually phrased using the "if..." clause in English, mathematical definitions are "if and only if" conditions.

Once the limit notation is defined, yes, your "if... then..." statement is true.

Comment: Thank you! really appreciated.